# Upload any video and convert to .mp4 online in .net

Tags: c#, .net, video, mp4

I have a strange requirement. User can upload their video of any format (or a limited format). We have to store them and convert them to **.mp4** format so we can play that in our site.

Same requirement also for audio files.

I have googled but I can't get any proper idea. Any help or suggestions....??

Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't know if this will help but there's an online converter - maybe view the source? http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

Comment: what .net language are you using asp/c sharp?

Comment: you might wanna check out https://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/

Comment: look at this blog http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/

Comment: http://www.doyourself.org/ffmpeg/588-ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide/

Comment: google ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide and you'll get a lot of stuff

Comment: thanks  I will try that and after that give updates..

Answer (score 13):

You can convert almost any video/audio user files to mp4/mp3 with [FFMpeg command line utility](http://www.ffmpeg.org). From .NET it can be called using wrapper library like [Video Converter for .NET](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) (this one is nice because everything is packed into one DLL):

```
(new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()).ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, pathToOutputMp4File, Formats.mp4)
```

Note that video conversion requires significant CPU resources; it's good idea to run it in background.

Comment: This throws an exception "An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in NReco.VideoConverter.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

Answer (score 8):

[Your Answer](https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/convert-viedo-flv-cnet-web-83983.aspx)

**please Replace .flv to .mp4 you will get your answer**

```
private bool ReturnVideo(string fileName)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        //rename if file already exists

        int j = 0;
        string AppPath;
        string inputPath;
        string outputPath;
        string imgpath;
        AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
        //Get the application path
        inputPath = AppPath + "OriginalVideo";
        //Path of the original file
        outputPath = AppPath + "ConvertVideo";
        //Path of the converted file
        imgpath = AppPath + "Thumbs";
        //Path of the preview file
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName);
        while (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            j = j + 1;
            int dotPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".");
            string namewithoutext = fileName.Substring(0, dotPos);
            string ext = fileName.Substring(dotPos + 1);
            fileName = namewithoutext + j + "." + ext;
            filepath = Server.MapPath("~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName);
        }
        try
        {
            this.fileuploadImageVideo.SaveAs(filepath);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        string outPutFile;
        outPutFile = "~/OriginalVideo/" + fileName;
        int i = this.fileuploadImageVideo.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        System.IO.FileInfo a = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(outPutFile));
        while (a.Exists == false)
        {

        }
        long b = a.Length;
        while (i != b)
        {

        }


        string cmd = " -i \"" + inputPath + "\\" + fileName + "\" \"" + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv" + "\"";
        ConvertNow(cmd);
        string imgargs = " -i \"" + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv" + "\" -f image2 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -s 280x200 -an \"" + imgpath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".jpg" + "\"";
        ConvertNow(imgargs);


        return true;
    }
    private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
    {
        string exepath;
        string AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
        //Get the application path
        exepath = AppPath + "ffmpeg.exe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
        //Path of exe that will be executed, only for "filebuffer" it will be "flvtool2.exe"
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        //The command which will be executed
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.Start();

        while (proc.HasExited == false)
        {

        }
    }
    protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReturnVideo(this.fileuploadImageVideo.FileName.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: @Tejas what is the second conversion for

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit old thread but if I get here other people see this too. You shoudn't use it process info to start ffmpeg. It is a lot to do with it. [Xabe.FFmpeg](https://xabe.net/product/xabe-ffmpeg/) you could do this by running just

```
await Conversion.Convert("inputfile.mkv", "file.mp4").Start()
```

This is one of easiest usage. This library provide fluent API to FFmpeg.

Comment: This shows a warning message. 

Conversion.Convert(string, string, bool) is obselete. This will be deleted in next major version. Please use FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet intead of that.

New usage is like this:

string output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".mp4");
            var snippet = FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Convert(Resources.MkvWithAudio, output);
            IConversionResult result = await snippet.Start();