# Upload any video and convert to .mp4 in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, video

I have a strange requirement. User can upload their video of any format (or a limited format). We have to store them and convert them to .mp4 format so we can play that in our site.

Any help or suggestions....??

Thanks in advance

Comment: upload the file then start an asynchronous process for video conversion

Comment: Did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694024/upload-any-video-and-convert-to-mp4-online-in-net

Comment: I will try this and check it  thank you Mr. Atish Dipongkor

Comment: I checked it sorry but i can't understand what he tried to says ..

Comment: @AtishDipongkor this question is identical, the first two lines of it anyway. I would advise commenting on that question rather than adding a new question.